# Nothing is showing up on my pop up window for JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to create a simple script that will allow a pop up of images and text. The window is poping up but its blank with nothing on it. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Thermomter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon cold = new ImageIcon("cold_thermomtor.png");

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(cold);
        label.setText("omg this is painfull");
            
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(label);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put

```
frame.add(label);
```

first, after:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(label);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

A call to `frame.pack();` before calling `setVisible(true)` will ensure all the elements inside get sized correctly before displaying them.

> The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes
> [...]

> [...] pack leaves the frame layout manager in charge of the frame size, and layout managers are good at adjusting to platform dependencies and other factors that affect component size.

Comment: (1-) Since JDK5 the show() method has been replaced by the `setVisible(true)` method.

Comment: ahh.. sorry I am getting old

Comment: Plus one for mentioning `pack()`. Please edit your answer to update to the `setVisible(true)` method indicated by @camickr, then remove the last sentence and the `<strike>`. IMO it would be a better approach, and a better answer than the accepted one. **Update:** BTW - also remove *"(dunno if actually necessary?)"*. Calling `pack` best practice for a number of reasons.